# setfocus for checkboxlist itemlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an `asp.net webform` which on one page I am using a `checkboxlist` which has 7 `listitems`.

I want to have the first `listitem` have the focus set to it.

All my other pages are set up as below but this doesn't work for `listitem` as you can not define an `id`.

```
<script runat="server">
     void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          SetFocus(Step02AllServices);
     }
</script>
```

I'd prefer to do this in JQuery/JavaScript but I'm open to all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkboxlist listitems` gets rendered as a series of `input` with `type="checkbox"`.
If you inspect the html that is rendered at browser, you will see that the ids and names of those inputs are very similar.
So you have to make a jquery selector that matches all those checkboxes, and focus on the first one, for example:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[name*="Step02AllServices$"]')[0].focus();
    });
</script>
```